# Unity 3d - Physical Class to Attend

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm interested in developing Apps with Unity 3d and I have a project coming in that could use it but I need a crash course.

When I started to develop for iOS I was able to find an awesome 4-day course and I can't seem to find anything similar for Unity 3d.

Can anyone recommend a similar course?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are training videos here:

1. http://www.design3.com/ with developer/designer community
2. http://www.3dbuzz.com/
3. http://www.digitaltutors.com/

Well, about interactive courses, I know about this one in US:
http://www.internaldrive.com/idga/courses/teen-game-development-iphone-android

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student or teacher/faculty I'd suggest to go to http://www.studica.com/software/tutorials/Unity-Training.html

You get all kinds of student discounts if you qualify.